# Objective C: AlertView does not work

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I am implementing an alert view after the user clicks on the 'destructButton' in an action sheet. Code snippet as below:

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if (buttonIndex != actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex)
  {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
     initWithTitle:@"Something happened!"
     message:nil
     delegate:nil
     cancelButtonTitle:@"Phew!"
     otherButtonTitles:nil];
  }

  [alert show];
  [alert release];
}
```

I have already included the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol in my .h file

```
@interface Control_FunViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    UITextField *nameField;
    UITextField *numberField;
    UILabel *sliderLabel;
    UISwitch *leftSwitch;
    UISwitch *rightSwitch;
    UIButton *doSomethingButton;

}
```

But when I click on the destructButton in the actionsheet, nothing happens. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Zhen

Comment: I don't think your code can even compile. Why `alert` is shown outside of the scope where it is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your delegate needs to implement `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.**

Action sheet will be dismissed after `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` and after that the delegate will receive `actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` .

From [Apple Action Sheet Delegate Protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html)

> ... the delegate must implement the
>   actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:
>   message to respond when those buttons
>   are clicked; otherwise, your custom
>   buttons do nothing. The action sheet
>   is automatically dismissed after the
>   **actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:**
>   delegate method is invoked.

You can have a look at example projects that use UIActionSheet like [GenericKeychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_DetailViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Classes_DetailViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) :

```
    // Action sheet delegate method.
    -      (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
        clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [passwordItem resetKeychainItem];
            [accountNumberItem resetKeychainItem];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added UIActionSheetDelegate on .h file. Not this only enough. You also have to set delegate for the UIActionSheet object. Refer this below coding:

-(void)showActionSheet
{
UIActionSheet *action =[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"dsfs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"First Btn" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Dest Btn" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [action showInView:self.view];

}

In that code, I have set the delegate of UIActionSheet to self, this works if you have added this method on your ViewController (Control_FunViewController).